# How to implement shadow mapping in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to implement shadows in a WebGL scene for the first time and as far as I know, the most straightforward way to do this is to use a shadow map, but I just can't find a tutorial explaining this concept, that isn't either about OpenGL or containing some library like three.js.

However, I've read, that I'll have to write two pairs of shaders. The first pair of shaders is used to build the shadow map, which somehow has to be stored in a framebuffer object. Then I would have to take the stored shadow map from the framebuffer and pass it to the second pair of shaders, that is used to draw the objects of my scene.

The shadow map must contain the information, what distance the light can travel from it's source before it hits an object, and with this information passed to the shader, which is used to draw an object, it would be possible to specify, which parts are lit by light from the light source and which parts are only lit by ambient light.

Well so much for theory, but I have no idea of how to get this working...

For experimenting, I've set up a pretty simple scene, rendering two spheres lit by a single point light source, which looks like this:

[image: spheres lit by point light]

Both spheres are created with their center at `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` and with radius `1.0`.

The matrix for the bigger sphere is translated by `[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0]` and scaled by `[2.0, 2.0, 2.0]`.

The matrix for the smaller sphere is translated by `[2.0, 0.0, 2.0]` and scaled by `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]`.

The position of the point light source is `[4.0, 0.0, 4.0]`.

So, the smaller sphere is now just between the bigger sphere and the light source, and therefore there should be an area on the surface of the bigger sphere, that is not lit directly.

The two shaders I use for this scene look like this:

**vertex shader**

```
  attribute vec4 aPosition;
  attribute vec3 aNormal;

  uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
  uniform mat3 uNormalMatrix;

  varying vec4 vPosition;
  varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;

  void main ( ) {
    vTransformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * aNormal;
    vPosition = uModelViewMatrix * aPosition;
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * vPosition;
  }
```

**fragment shader**

```
  precision highp float;

  uniform vec3 uLightPosition;

  varying vec4 vPosition;
  varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;

  void main ( ) {
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uLightPosition - vPosition.xyz);

    float diffuseLightWeighting = max(
        dot(normalize(vTransformedNormal), lightDirection), 0.0);

    vec3 lightWeighting = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1) +
        vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) * diffuseLightWeighting;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * lightWeighting, 1.0);
  }
```

So, the first thing I'd have to do now would be to write another pair of shaders, and because they're not used to actually draw something, I can omit the attribute for the normals as well as the uniform for the normal matrix, and also there's no need for a projection matrix, right?

The second vertex shader could then look like that:

```
  attribute vec4 aPosition;

  uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;

  varying vec4 vPosition;

  void main ( ) {
    vPosition = uModelViewMatrix * aPosition;
    gl_Position = vPosition;
  }
```

But what about the fragment shader? And, anyway, how do I find out where the light from the point light source hits an object? I mean, that would generally require to pass in the vertex position data from *all* relevant objects *at once*, wouldn't it? (Though in this particular case it'd only be neccessary to pass in the vertex positions of the smaller sphere...)

Now, my question is, how do I go on from here? What has to be written into the fragment shader, how do I save the shadow map and how can I use it to calculate the shadow of the smaller sphere on the bigger sphere?

I fear that I maybe demand too much, but it would be great if someone could at least point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/

Basically, as you found out, the shadow mapping is done with 2 passes. The first pass writes/renders to a depth texture from the **point of view of the light source** which is then used in the second pass to determine if the pixel is in shadow. The idea is basically that if the pixel is further from the light than the shadowmap depth/distance, then this means that the scene contains another object that is closer to the light/blocks the light. AKA, the current pixel is in the shadow.

The first pass shader is basically a standard vertex shader with a empty fragment shader that render to a depth texture. Depth texture is a pretty well supported extension at the moment.

In the second pass, you need to setup some way to do the depth comparison as mentioned above. Then basically you calculate a shadow value, usually 1 or 0 based on the result of the depth comparison and use that in the lighting calculations. For example, shadow value of 1 blocks diffuse light and specular light contributions.

As for how to change the render output destination, you need to use the FrameBuffer Objects.

The complete setup may look something like this:

```
// HANDLE VBOS

fbo_shadow.setAsDrawTarget();
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

shadow_depth_shader.use();
shadow_depth.setUnif("u_viewProjection", lightMatrix);

// DRAW EVERYTHING

fbo_lightPass.setAsDrawTarget();
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

lighting_pass_shader.use();
lighting_pass_shader.setUnif("u_shadowMap", fbo_shadow.depthTexture);
lighting_pass_shader.setUnif("u_viewProjection", camera.getVPMatrix());
// other unifs ...

// DRAW EVERYTHING AGAIN
```

EDIT: added a sample shadowCalculation function for the fragment shader:

```
float shadowCalculation(vec4 fragPosLightSpace, sampler2D u_shadowMap, float bias){
   // perform perspective divide and map to [0,1] range
   vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz/fragPosLightSpace.w;
   projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;
   float shadowDepth = texture2D(u_shadowMap, projCoords.xy).r;
   float depth = projCoords.z;
   float shadow = step(depth-bias,shadowDepth);
   return shadow;
}
```

Comment: Hello Wacław and thank you very much for your answer! Well, if I got you right, the _first_ step for me to take would be to create a `lightMatrix`, that should be a mat4. So, in the vertex shader for the first pass, it would look like `vPosition = lightMatrix * modelViewMatrix * aPosition`, or would I have to take the projectionMatrix into account too, like `vPosition = uProjectionMatrix * lightMatrix * modelViewMatrix * aPosition`? To retrieve the vec3 for the second pass, I'd then have to use something like glMatrix `vec4.transformMat4` by adding `1` as the fourth value, right?

Comment: I also kind of struggle to find something about depth textures: The MSDN doesn't describe this extension at all and the MDN only has a dead link. The basic syntax should be `depthTexture = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_depth_texture')`, right? Do you have any link where I can see which Browsers do support this feature? _caniuse.com_ isn't that useful concerning WebGL and the networks mentioned above aren't either. I remember that I have read something about storing the values as RGBA values of a normal texture, so that could work as a fallback? It seems learningwebgl.com is gone offline...

Comment: ...which is **very** sad, because if I remember correctly, there was a lesson about how to use the frameBuffer object to make a texture that can be used in a second pass. I never used this technique and therefore I only have some vague ideas about how it works, - and now I just can't find an article or tutorial which explains this. But, that's a big problem anyway for me: If you want to learn pure WebGL, it is so hard to find any articles, documentations and tutorials! It's like trying to learn JavaScript and everything you find around the web is just about jQuery or Java. :-(

Comment: Dont have time for a better answer atm, go to http://webglfundamentals.org/ for tutorial on webGL. http://webglstats.com/ for webgl availability.

Comment: It's fantastic that you try to help me anyway! So, don't rush! ;-) I already knew _webglfundamentals.org_ and didn't think there was something about using framebuffers, but you're right! - There indeed is an explanation in the article about _image processing_ that I have overlooked when I checked first time. Also _webglstats.com_ seems very useful! Thank you very much!

Comment: The lightMatrix is a view projection matrix from the point of view of light source so it should just be `lightMatrix * modelMatrix * aPosition`. For the second pass the implementation is dependent on how you want to setup the depth comparision. The way I do is to transform each vertex into `lightSpace` using the same `lightMatrix` with the same calculations. So the VS would calculate the `gl_Position` using the `viewProjection matrix` from your camera but also output a `v_fragPosLightSpace` to the FS to do the depth comparison. I hope you figured out how to use the extension and FBOS :).

Comment: If you choose to use the same setup as I do you may find the `shadowCalculation` snippet in the answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a strange type but very helpful.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400">
    </canvas>
    <script src="https://www.drawing3d.de/bridge.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.drawing3d.de/WebDrawing3d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.drawing3d.de/Classes.js"></script>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var WebDevice = new Device(canvas);
        WebDevice.Shadow = true;
        WebDevice.Paint = draw;
        WebDevice.Refresh();
        function draw() {
        WebDevice.drawBox(new xyz(-10,-10,-1),new xyz(20,20,1));
        WebDevice.drawSphere(new xyz(0, 0, 5), 5);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```